# chrome extension change icon dynamically (without clicking)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change the icon dynamically but it doesn't work with what I use so if someone can help, here is my code

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (msg.action === "onStream") {
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(d){
            var tabId = d[0].id;
            if (msg.value) {
                chrome.action.setIcon({path: "icons/on.png", tabId: tabId});
            } else {
                chrome.action.setIcon({path: "icons/off.png", tabId: tabId});
            }
        })
    }
});
```

content script who I call background script with this

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'onStream',
    value: true
});
```

and my manifest

```
{
  "name": "title",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/Logo16.png",
    "48": "icons/Logo48.png",
    "128": "icons/Logo128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/Logo16.png",
      "48": "icons/Logo48.png",
      "128": "icons/Logo128.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us how you run the content script.

Comment: <script src="main.js"></script> I call it from the popup.html , the main problem is it's not dynamic

Comment: This is not how content scripts are executed, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).